# "jump out" of keyup() event

Tags: jquery

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){

     if(e.which === 13){
         //if enter is pressed
         //ignore the rest of the code below
     }

     doStuff();
});
```

What would be the correct syntax for skipping the rest of the code under certain conditions (like when enter is pressed for example). I know that i would just wrap it in if statements, but I would like to know if there is something similar to `return false;`.

However, I'm aware of that return false does both an `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`, and that's not obviously really what I'm after in this case. Return a boolean value perhaps?

Comment: just use `return;` to exit the callback without changing the behavior.

Comment: @KevinB: That was an *answer*, not a comment. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for clearing it up for me. Mixed it up a bit with jumping out of $.each by returning boolean values.

Comment: @Johan: Glad that helped. It's the same thing in both cases, actually. If you return from the iterator function in `$.each` (or `each`) via `return;`, it doesn't stop the iteration. Only `return false;`, specifically, does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have a followup question that might be a bit more tricky: What if I call a function in the if statement. Is there any way to return; the keyup function from my other function. Perhaps there is a way to pass a reference to it?

Comment: @Johan: Nope, you have to have that function return a value and then use an `if` to decide whether to `return;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a `return` statement can also do this.`return` will cause the function to exit immediately, any code after it won't be executed.

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){

     if(e.which === 13){
         //if enter is pressed
         //ignore the rest of the code below
         return;
     }

     doStuff();
});
```

**Edit :**

T.J.Crowder has put this precious information in comment. So just putting it here as I agree with it.

It's useful to know that there's no significant difference in JavaScript between a function not using the `return` statement at all (so, just "returning" by reaching the end of its code), using `return;` without an argument, and using `return undefined;`. In all three cases, the code calling the function sees undefined as a the result of the call.

Comment: Good call moving the comment into the answer. I should have done that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, I had not thought putting those details and honestly I was not aware of `return undefined;` :)